# Getting TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value when running firebase emulators:start

Tags: firebase, npm, typeerror, firebase-tools

Just updated firebase-tools to 8.4.0 and now getting the following error when running firebase emulators:start:

> ⚠  TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
>       at Proxy. (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:311:83)

Please let me know of any additional info needed!

Comment: This is a bug on firebase-tools, which according to [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2273#issuecomment-632518009) has been introduced in 8.3.0. This same comment suggests downgrading to 8.2.0

Comment: I've noticed you're running this on node 13. If you don't mind, could please try running it on node 10?

Comment: Yes, had wanted to upgrade to use the UI. I tried running on node 10.20.1 and still get: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value at Proxy.<anonymous> (/Users/USER/.nvm/versions/node/v10.20.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:311:83)

Comment: can you show how you're calling `admin.initializeApp()` on your functions/index.js ?

Comment: The latest [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2273#issuecomment-634056715) on the issue referenced by @RosárioPereiraFernandes says _In general nobody should be using initializeApp(functions.config().firebase) anymore. The plain initializeApp() is preferred._

Answer (score 2):

The latest [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2273#issuecomment-634056715) on the issue referenced by @RosárioPereiraFernandes says:

> In general nobody should be using
>   `initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)` anymore. The plain
>   `initializeApp()` is preferred.

I can attest that calling `initializeAdd()` without passing any arguments allows the emulator to start properly.

Comment: Meanwhile, 8.4.1 has been released:  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.4.1

Answer (score 1):

It's a regression in 8.3.0 and 8.4.0. For now downgrade to 8.2.0

```
npm i -g firebase-tools@8.2.0
```

Comment: with 8.2 I cant use the new emulator UI features though ?

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html?m=1

Comment: Exactly the same as @FriedrichCoen, I had upgraded to be able to use the new emulator UI